# How to hide a link for 10 sec on a Facebook tab

Tags: facebook

how can I hide a link for 10 sec, eg Click Share and wait 10 seconds and the link will appear.
In facebook TAB

Answer (score 1):

This is very general, but if you use jquery for example you could use [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```
$('#my-link').hide().delay(10000).show();
```

Comment: In which facebook tab should I put this , In Static Html doesn't work

Comment: @Edon Gashi See this guide http://www.snipe.net/2009/10/mini-site-facebook-static-fbml/

Comment: How can I make a code , eg When I click Share PAge button to redirect me to another site

Comment: Open another question , it's not related to the current question.
Actually , search for old question FIRST , and after that open a question.

Answer (score 0):

In case you can use JS in your app, you can use

```
<script>

function showLink()
{
 var link = document.getElemenyById('the_link');
 link.class = "visibleToAll";
}

window.setTimeout('showLink()',10000);

</script>
<style>
.hiddenFromAll{
 display:none;
}
.visibleToAll{
 display:inline;
}
</style>
<div id='the_link' class='hiddenFromAll'>
http://www.bla.com
</div>
```